# Load balancing many services on few GCE nodes

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have 2 GCE nodes, each running the same N services. For each service, I use the GCE network load balancer to distribute requests to the 2 nodes. I therefore created the following setup:

- Since I want the load balancer to check the health of each service separately, I have a health check for each of the N services (every health check checks a different port for an HTTP response)
- Since each service has its own health check, I have N target-pools, all of them just containing node 1 and 2, but all with a different health check.
- Since I have N target pools, I also have N forwarding rules
- Since I want each of these load balanced services to be available externally (actually, from within GAE), I assign each of the forwarding rules a static IP address

The problem is that I have more than 7 services I want to run, and the regional quota of GCE only allow 7 static IP addresses. This makes me suspect I'm doing something wrong, and there's a better design for what I'm doing.

The root of my problem seems to be that I want a health check for each service (instead of each node), which I can only seem to do if I split up the entire path up to the forwarding rule in the GCE network load balancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration looks reasonable, given that each service has its own dedicated health-check.

Note that if you need more than the default resource quotas and your project is not in Free Trial stage, you can request more quota using the [quota change request form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform).